# Understanding this very generic divergence theorem where the open set have border $C^k$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis, divergence-operator

I'm at a PDE class and my teacher gave a very generic definition of the divergence theorem. I can't find it anywhere. It's something like this:

Definition: let $k\in \{1,2,\cdots,\infty\}$, $N\ge 2$

> An open $\Omega\in\mathbb{R}^N$ has border of class $C^k$ if:
>
> $\Omega$ is bounded and given any $x_0\in\partial\Omega$, there is an
>   open $U_0$ containing $x_0$ and a diffeomorphism $\psi:U_0\to Q$,
>   where $Q = ]-1,1[^N$ such that
>
> 1. $\psi(\Omega\cap U_0) = \{t\in Q: t_N>0\}$
> 2. $\psi(x_0) = 0$
> 3. $\psi(\partial \Omega\cap U_0) = \{t\in Q: t_N = 0\}$

Now he wrote these things:

$X(t) = \psi^{-1}(t_1,\cdots,t_{N-1}, 0)$

$X:\{t'\in\mathbb{R}^{N-1}:|t_j|<1, j=1,\cdots,N-1\}\to U_0\cap\partial\Omega$

$$\vec{\theta}(t') = \left(\frac{\partial(x_2,\cdots,x_N)}{\partial(t_1,\cdots,t_{N-1)}}(t'),\cdots,\frac{\partial(x_1,\cdots,x_N)}{\partial(t_1,\cdots,t_{N-1)}}(t')\right)$$

then $\vec{\theta}(t')$ is normal to $\partial\Omega\cap U_0$ at $X(t')$

*What are those derivatives? I don't recognize this notation and I don't know how it can be normal to anything. And why he picked the inverse image of $\psi$?*

The surface element $d\sigma$ of $\partial\Omega$ is represented in $U_0\cap \partial \Omega$ by

$$|\vec{\theta}(t')|dt_1\cdots dt_{N-1}$$

finally we can define the exterior unitary normal in $\partial \Omega$:

$$\vec{n}:\partial\Omega\to\mathbb{R}^N$$

$$|\vec{n}(p)| = 1, \forall p\in \partial \Omega$$

> **Divergence Theorem**
>
> Let $\Omega$ be an open with boundary class $C^k$ and $\vec{X}(x) =
>  (X_1(x), \cdots, X_N(x))$ with $X_j\in C^1(\overline{\Omega}),
>  j=1,\cdots, N$ then
>
> $$\int_{\Omega}(\mbox{div} \vec{X})(x)dx =
>  \int_{\partial\Omega}\vec{X}(y)\cdot\vec{n}(y)d\sigma(y)$$

This seems to be a very generic view of the divergence theorem. And it seems that I need to understand what is an open set with a border and what does it mean for it to have class $C^k$. I also need to understand the surface element $d\sigma$.

Is there a place where I can learn about those things but not too deep? They're just tools to solve PDEs

Also, what does $C^n(\Omega)$ means?

Also, the integral on $\Omega$ is supposed to be on an open of $\mathbb{R}^n$, but $div$ applied to $x$ is a real number, and $dx$ looks like a one dimensional thing.

**UPDATE:**

I'm downloading some books on vector calculus but I only find ones with a lot of wedge products and differential forms. I needed only a vector explanation of all this. Can someone point me a gook book?

Comment: What do you mean by $Q=]-1, 1[$?

Comment: $C^n(\Omega)$ means $\vec X$ has continuous partial derivatives of order $n$.

Comment: @manooooh it means that every partial derivative of order up to $n$ in any point $\Omega$ is continuous?

Comment: @JackyChong I think the teacher meant open set $(1,1)$

Comment: Then how is it a diffeomorphism?

Comment: @JackyChong I don't know, I'm very confused

Comment: Well, you have a few typos here. For example, Q should be $Q=]-1,1[^N$.

Comment: $\psi$ should be a $C^k$-diffeomorphism in the first definition.

Comment: In the definition of $\theta$, the components should most probably have alternating $\pm1$.

Comment: @timur corrected $Q$

Comment: @timur what those partials mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just the usual divergence theorem written in an explicit coordinate notation. Any introductory book on multivariate calculus treats it.

First, $C^k(\Omega)$ is the space of $C^k$ functions on the set $\Omega$. The integral is an $N$-dimensional integral, where $dx$ is an $N$-dimensional volume element.

Here $\psi$ is a map that transforms a piece of the domain near its boundary into a domain with flat boundary (in this case the latter is just a half cube). Think of a bite out of an apple, and turning that small portion of the apple into one with flat boundary. This is called flattening out of the boundary. Boundary smoothness is defined by how smooth you can choose $\psi$ to be.

Then $X(t)$ is simply a parametrization of a boundary piece, where $t\in\mathbb{R}^{N-1}$. Since $\psi$ maps the boundary piece into a domain in $\mathbb{R}^{N-1}$, its inverse gives you a parametrization of that piece.

The derivative notation means the determinant of the matrix formed by the indicated partial derivatives. Let $\phi=\psi^{-1}$. Then $X$ is simply the restriction of $\phi$ on $\{t_N=0\}$. The Jacobian determinant of $\phi$ is
$$
J = \frac{\partial(x_1,\ldots,x_N)}{\partial(t_1,\ldots,t_N)}=\begin{vmatrix}\frac{\partial x_1}{\partial t_1}&\frac{\partial x_1}{\partial t_2}&\cdots&\frac{\partial x_1}{\partial t_N}\\\frac{\partial x_2}{\partial t_1}&\frac{\partial x_2}{\partial t_2}&\cdots&\frac{\partial x_2}{\partial t_N}\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\\frac{\partial x_N}{\partial t_1}&\frac{\partial x_N}{\partial t_2}&\cdots&\frac{\partial x_N}{\partial t_N}\end{vmatrix}.
$$
The vector $\theta$ is defined by the expansion coefficients of this determinant with respect to the last column (This is why I think there should be alternating signs in the formula of $\theta$. Just think of a surface in 3D space, where we use cross product). Note that the first $N-1$ columns of this matrix constitutes a basis of tangent vectors to the boundary. So taking an inner product of $\theta$ with any tangent vector $V$ would be equivalent to computing the above determinant with the last column replaced by $V$. Since $V$ is spanned by the first $N-1$ columns, the determinant will be $0$, meaning that $\theta$ is orthogonal to the tangent plane.

Let me elaborate on the tangent basis bit. Fix all $t_2,\ldots,t_N$ and look at $\phi(t_1,t_2,\ldots,t_N)$ as a function of $t_1$. It would draw a curve along the boundary of $\Omega$. If you take the derivative of this function, you would get a vector tangent to the boundary:
$$
V_1 = \big(\frac{\partial x_1}{\partial t_1},\frac{\partial x_2}{\partial t_1},\ldots,\frac{\partial x_N}{\partial t_1}\big).
$$
This is simply the first column of the Jacobian matrix of $\phi$. By the same reasoning, we see that the first $N-1$ columns of the Jacobian matrix of $\phi$ are vectors tangent to the boundary surface. Also, as $\phi$ is a diffeomorphism, its Jacobian matrix is invertible, and hence those $N-1$ vectors are linearly independent. This shows that they form a basis of the tangent space.

Comment: Things are a LOT more clear now. But what do you mean by expansion coefficients? You mean that $\theta$ components are pieces of this jacobian determinant? I can't see how the first $N-1$ columns constitute a basis of tangent vectors to the boundary. Could you elaborate more on that? I can open a bounty if needed, I know this is a lot.

Comment: You know you can expand a determinant in terms of its row or column? Cofactors or minors ring a bell?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs: Have a look at the update.

Comment: If I start with $\frac{\partial x_1}{\partial t_1}$ then by eliminating its row and column I should get $\frac{\partial(x_2,\cdots,x_N}{t_2,\cdots,t_N}$ so it doesn't match the $\theta$'s first element

Comment: Shuldn't it be $X(t_1,\cdots,t_N)$ instead of $\theta$?

Comment: You need to eliminate by the *last* column, not the first one.

Comment: what is $\frac{\partial x_1}{\partial t_1}$? Are them the coordinates $(x_1(t),x_2(t),\cdots,x_{n-1}(t),0)$ of $\psi^{-1}$? At some point you call them $t_1,\cdots,t_N$ but sometimes it's $x_1$ etc. I'm confused. Could you explain whats happening?

Comment: I also don't get why if I take the derivative I get a vector tangent to the boundary.

Comment: Yes the coordinates of $\psi^{-1}$. I don't think I called them differently. Please point at a specific location where I changed notation from $t_i$ to $x_k$.

Comment: Take a parametrized curve. What is the derivative of it wrt to the parameter?

Comment: For example, $(x(t),y(t) = (2t,t^3)$. I don't see how to derive with respect to the first coordinate. Only with respect to $t$.

Comment: the derivative would be $(2,3t^2)$, which is tangent to the curve

Comment: But this is the derivative with respect to $t$, not with respect to the first coordinate, which is $2t$. That's why I was in doubt. And in general this is not true. Not all derivatives of paths will be tangent, or will them? Also, how does this explain the tangent $\phi$? I can't see a path. This question has a bounty, so if you could write an answer I'd give it to you. Thank you so much

Comment: This answer is complete. Please read it carefully.

Comment: I get everything, but I don't understand the geometry of why $\phi$ restricted to run on $t_1$ only, will be tangent to the boundary. Is there somewhere I can read it better? With a pratical example? When you say $\phi$ restricted to run on $t_1$ will give a curve along the boundary, I imagine any curve, not necessairly tangent. I' confused